# How to configure winform app to pull files from dvd drive with installation media?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am creating an application that uses various files to function (Media files) now for security (piracy) reason I would like to keep the files on the installation media (CD) and only install the application's core files onto the target PC, there after when the program runs I want to point it to the CD/DVD drive containing the installation media. The application will then run when the files are located in the path specified. I can easly set the default path however I do not know how to find the right drive letter nor do i know how stop the program from running when the disc is not in the drive 
TLDR:

1. In the same way the old PC games would work I want to do the same
   for my win application i.e. The game needs the disc inserted to run.
2. The application will not run without the disc as the application

   files (media files) will be kept on the disc not computer.

Answer (score 0):

If I where to do it I would record what drive letter the CD was located in during the install process then hard code that drive letter in to the settings of your program.

However I don't think it will be worth it.

You are going to add a increased hassle for your users who are not pirating and all a person who wants to pirate your program is going to do is just use a CD copying software or use a virtual CD software that can mount a ISO. The reason new PC games don't do this any more is ***this copy protection no longer works*** due to the low barrier of entry for someone to copy a CD or create a virtual one.

Comment: I am using a separate application that hides the media file folder from cd copying osftware. I am aware it will be a hassle for users which is why i want to make is fairly simple in that it strictly just looks for the files i nthe drive before the application menu loads